# Release memory in R

Tags: r, oracle, memory

I have 2 questions:
1.How can I release memory after get it? 
I wanna get a lot of memory from server, for some minutes and then I wanna release that for usage of others. With running "rm" command that space is released but the memory usage of R is not decreased.
We can test this situation by these commands to see Task Manager status:

```
n=20000
d=dist(data.frame(x=rnorm(n),y=rnorm(n)))
rm(list=ls())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the command to release memory is `gc()`. It will show the change in memory consumption in Task Manager as well. You probably actually don't need to use it to make the memory available, but I'm not completely sure about it. All I know is that Task Manager is not reliable in these cases. There is specialized software that helps with it though.
2. I have no idea what ORE is. Do you have an actual problem where the memory is limiting factor or are you just trying to get a feel how these things work with R?

Comment: Thanks, `gc()` is helpful. About ORE(Oracle R Enterprise), I have an actual problem, because in spite of existence a server I can't use its ability.